# web3 transaction value always 0

Tags: web3js, nodejs, ethereumj

Can anyone explain to me, why the transaction object I receive via web3 always has a value of 0?

When I open up the transactionhash in etherscan, it shows under the to field which is named "interacted with" that a certain amount of tokens had been transfered, but my code returns transaction.value of 0.

Sorry, I am new to the whole topic.

Regards

Comment: Can u show some code and pictures

Comment: I think I found out the reason cause I filter for token addresses. I came across a post that said token transfers always have a value of 0 and the amount of tokens must be extracted from the transaction receipts data field. I am just not sure how to parse the data value to something that looks like a token amount. 

Data example in my receipt
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007eaf658

Any idea how I can get the token amount out of that using web3?

Comment: The transaction value is the amount of ether that has been sent with the tx. The amount of transfered tokens can be shown in the logs of tx receipt. You  need to ask another question for that and try to look for how to decode transfer event with web3js

Comment: I think that is hex decimal and u need to convert it to decimal will give u probably 7 tokens